# How to get email template order status url create in Magento 2

Tags: magento

url variable
{{trans 'Order #%increment_id' increment_id=$order.increment_id |raw}}

ORDER STATUS

Answer (score 0):

ORDER STATUS

{{var order.getIncrementId()}}

variable create for increment id